# Why am I getting this error, while building in android using "react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I have followed each and every step carefully that in given in the official react native documentation. While running this command "react-native run-android" I am getting this error

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- Where:
  `Script '/home/gautam/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 156`
- What went wrong:

Could not compile script `'/home/gautam/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'.`

```
startup failed:
  script '/home/gautam/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle': 156: unable to resolve class FileTreeBuilder 
   @ line 156, column 27.
         final FileTreeBuilder treeBuilder = new FileTreeBuilder(outputDir)
                               ^

  script '/home/gautam/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle': 156: unable to resolve class FileTreeBuilder 
   @ line 156, column 41.
     FileTreeBuilder treeBuilder = new FileTr
                                   ^

  2 errors
```

- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.